# Fixing return format for my function

Tags: python, list, format, sequence

The code for my function works correctly, but it is not returning the function in the format I would like. The function counts seed values in a 2nd sequence and then is supposed to return the seed counts as a list of integers. It is returning the seed counts but on separate lines rather then in a list. Here is my code and what its returning in command prompt.

```
    def count_each(seeds,xs):
        for c in seeds:
            count=0
        for d in xs:
            if c==d:
                count=count+1
        print ([count])
```

count_each([10,20],[10,20,30,10])

count_each([4,8],[1,2,4,4,4,8,8,10])

In command prompt, I would like this function to print [2,1] for count_each([10,20],[10,20,30,10]) and [3,2] for count_each([4,8],[1,2,4,4,4,8,8,10]) but instead it is printing each seed value on its own line like so

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXAd3.png

In the picture above it prints [2], [1], [3], and [2] on separate lines when it should instead print just two lines of [2,1] and [3,2] for the two sequences. How can I have the function return the seed values for each sequence as a list instead of having the values on separate lines.

Edit: I need to accomplish this without importing from other modules and with the simplest code possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost done, but if you want to print the output in a list you must first create a list.Here, try this:

```
def count_each(seeds,xs):
    output = []
    for c in seeds:
        count=0
        for d in xs:
            if c==d:
                count=count+1
        output.append(count)
    print (output)
```

Comment: Thank you so much this solution works perfectly. The other answer wanted me to use completely different code but you have kept most of my original code in tact.

Comment: @famguy74 I am glad i helped, but you should try to explore python modules if you want to learn the language.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code does not work. Try this:

```
def count_each(seeds,xs):
    from collections import Counter
    counter_dict = dict(Counter(xs))
    count = []
    for s in seeds:
        count.append(counter_dict[s])
    print count

if __name__ == "__main__":
    count_each([10,20],[10,20,30,10])
    count_each([4,8],[1,2,4,4,4,8,8,10])
```

Basically, `Counter` gives you a count for each unique element in a list.

## Update:

Just found a `count` method for Python's `list`. The code is as follows:

```
def count_each(seeds,xs):
    from collections import Counter
    count = []
    for s in seeds:
        count.append(xs.count(s))
    print count
```

Comment: the code I have does work, I included a photo of it running in command prompt. I need to accomplish this without importing from other modules there must be a simpler way to just print these values as a list instead of individual values

Comment: No it does not. I copied your code and tried. It gave me [1] and [2], respectively. If you look at your code, you can see that your `count` variable is an integer not a list. Even if you do `[count]`, it is still a one-element list. Plus, `collections` is a built-in package. See my update for the `count` method of `list` objects.

Comment: if you add count_each([10,20],[10,20,30,10]) to the end of my code you can see that it does return [2] and [1] which its supposed to but I would just like it to return as [2,1] instead since they are part of the same sequence. Is importing counter really the only way to do this? There has to be a way to revise the loop and value of count to have it return lists of the sequence instead of separate integers

Comment: I am not sure what you're saying. Your code does not return list, which is what you wanted to achieve. See my update for not importing.